# Think ..... and you'll get the prize

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, flags

### Once you figure out how to approach the puzzle below, try to find the *hidden* four-word phrase.

---

**Skillful and experienced, single**

**Flexible and agile, on a shirt**

**"To", in it's natural state**

**Chest, vehicle**

**Shoot, came together**

**Companion, part of the back**

**Rubbish, annoy**

**Miss is a?, a future animal inside**

**Long animal, shoot**

**On snow, cold**

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Some images appear twice. Is that intentional?

Comment: @ACB Yes, it's intentional

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The hidden 4-word phrase is:

> **A LETTER IN COMMON**

The first thing I did was identify the countries and territories whose flags were depicted and also...

> ...list their [2-letter ISO codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_3166_country_codes) (out of force of habit, I guess):
>
>  Bolivia (BO) + Isle of Man (IM)
>  Panama (PA) + Austria (AT)
>  Saint Helena (SH) + Guernsey (GG)
>  Canada (CA) + Ireland (IE)
>  Canada (CA) + Ireland (IE)
>  Saint Helena (SH) + Guernsey (GG)
>  Faroe Islands (FO) + Aruba (AW)
>  Slovakia (SK) + Cyprus (CY)
>  Burundi (BI) + Antigua & Barbuda (AG)
>  Peru (PE) + Argentina (AR)
>  Puerto Rico (PR) + Niger (NE)
>  Anguilla (AI) + Ethiopia (ET)
>  Anguilla (AI) + Ethiopia (ET)
>  Puerto Rico (PR) + Niger (NE)
>  Burundi (BI) + Antigua & Barbuda (AG)

Then I noticed that...

> ...there are 10 different flag pairs listed (some multiple times) - the same number as the number of what appear to be pairs of definitions in the list at the top of the puzzle. I reasoned that there may well be a one-to-one correspondence between the two, and so we should look for a way to connect the definition pairs and the flags.

I then spotted that...

> ...many of the definitions appeared to clue 3-letter words, e.g. 'came together' = MET, 'Companion' = PAL, 'Skilful and experienced' = PRO, 'single' = ONE...
>
>  Moreover, in each case, these words contained 2-letter sequences that appeared in the country ISO codes: M(ET), (PA)L, (PR)O, O(NE)...
>
>  And even more interestingly, within these words flags depicted on the left appeared at the left-hand end of a word - (PA)L, (PR)O - and flags depicted on the right appeared at the right-hand end of a word - M(ET), O(NE).
>
>  And still even *more* interestingly, for the two words that paired up - (PR)O and O(NE) - the flags also paired up, and the additional letter in both words was *the same* ('O').

This led me to a hypothesis:

> Perhaps all of the definition pairs clue two 3-letter words of the form ABX and XCD, where 'AB' and 'CD' are the ISO codes of a pair of countries in the flag diagrams below, and 'X' is a common letter.

And it turned out I was right!

> *Note: Not all are strict definitions - some are more word association...*
>
>  Skillful and experienced (**PRO**), single  (**ONE**) = O
>  Flexible and agile (**CAT**), on a shirt (**TIE**) = T
>  "To" (**FOR**), in it's natural state (**RAW**) = R
>  Chest (**PEC**), vehicle (**CAR**) = C
>  Shoot (**AIM**), came together (**MET**) = M
>  Companion (**PAL**), part of the back (**LAT**) = L
>  Rubbish (**BIN**), annoy (**NAG**) = N
>  Miss is a? (**SHE**), a future animal inside (**EGG**) = E
>  Long animal (**BOA**), shoot (**AIM**) = A
>  On snow (**SKI**), cold (**ICY**) = I

Finally, we can...

> ...decode the flag pairs by replacing them with the 'common letter' that they map to in the corresponding clues:
>
>  Bolivia (BO) - **A** - Isle of Man (IM)
>  Panama (PA) - **L** - Austria (AT)
>  Saint Helena (SH) - **E** - Guernsey (GG)
>  Canada (CA) - **T** - Ireland (IE)
>  Canada (CA) - **T** - Ireland (IE)
>  Saint Helena (SH) - **E** - Guernsey (GG)
>  Faroe Islands (FO) - **R** - Aruba (AW)
>  Slovakia (SK) - **I** - Cyprus (CY)
>  Burundi (BI) - **N** - Antigua & Barbuda (AG)
>  Peru (PE) - **C** - Argentina (AR)
>  Puerto Rico (PR) - **O** - Niger (NE)
>  Anguilla (AI) - **M** - Ethiopia (ET)
>  Anguilla (AI) - **M** - Ethiopia (ET)
>  Puerto Rico (PR) - **O** - Niger (NE)
>  Burundi (BI) - **N** - Antigua & Barbuda (AG)

Which read in order spells out the answer:

> **A LETTER IN COMMON** - which is exactly what these 3-letter country-substring words have!

Comment: You got it, great job!